# React with using of Routes change css style of a div in another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I basically need to change the background by clicking Power button in component Header:

Header.js

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { faHome, faBars, faChevronLeft, faPowerOff, faBolt } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import App from '../app/App';
import { useState } from 'react';

const Header = () => {
    const [style, setStyle] = useState("profile-hidden");

    const changeStyle = () => {
      console.log("clicked");
    
      setStyle("profile-displayed");
    };

    return (
        <App style={style} />
        <div class="container-fluid ">           
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col px-0">
                    <div className="header d-flex justify-content-around">
                        <Link to='/'>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg img-btn" onClick={setBars}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} size="xl" /></button>
                        </Link>
                        <Link to='/video'>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg img-btn" onClick={ChevronLeft}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBolt} size="xl" /></button>
                        </Link>
                        <Link to='/video'>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg img-btn"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} size="xl"/></button>
                        </Link>
                        <Link to='/video'>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg img-btn" onClick={changeStyle}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPowerOff} size="xl"/></button>
                        </Link>   
                          
                    </div>
                </div>       
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}


export default Header;
```

index.js

I had to move Router from `App.js` to `index.js` otherwise it was giving error You cannot render `<Router>` inside another `<Router>`.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/app/App'

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import './app.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Header from '../header/Header';
import Footer from '../footer/Footer';
import Main from '../pages/main/Main';
import Video from '../pages/video/Video';
import Audio from '../pages/audio/Audio';
import Climate from '../pages/climate/Climate';
import Floorheat from '../pages/floorheat/Floorheat';
import Lights from '../pages/lights/Lights';
import Shades from '../pages/shades/Shades';

const App = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className={props.style}> 
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/video" element={<Video />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Main />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/audio" element={<Audio />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/climate" element={<Climate />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/floorheat" element={<Floorheat />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/lights" element={<Lights />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/shades" element={<Shades />}></Route>
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

As soon as I add `<App style={style} />` in `Header.js` browser hangs.
How to pass data to `App.js`?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see you need your state inside your `App` component because that is the "highest" component and where you want to use it.

You can move your state to the `App` component like so, and pass the `changeStyle` function to the `Header` component.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [style, setStyle] = useState("profile-hidden");

  const changeStyle = () => {
    setStyle("profile-displayed");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={props.style}>
        <Header onChangeStyle={changeStyle} />
        ...
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Then in the `Header` you can get the `onChangeStyle` function from the `props` and pass it to your button.

You should remove the `App` component in the `Header` since this will create a loop since `Header` is in `App` and vice versa, this is why your browser "hangs".

```js
const Header = ({ onChangeStyle }) => {
  return (
    <div class="container-fluid ">
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col px-0">
          <div className="header d-flex justify-content-around">
            ...
            <Link to="/video">
              <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-lg img-btn"
                onClick={onChangeStyle}
              >
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPowerOff} size="xl" />
              </button>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `App` component like you did in the `Header` isn't valid JSX since a React component ***must*** return a single node. You could solve this by wrapping each in a `React.Fragment`, `<>`, or any other HTML element like a `div`.

Doing this though will lead to a render loop since the `App` component is already rendering the `Header` component, so if the `Header` component renders `App`... this creates an infinite recursive render and the browser will effectively crash.

Lift the styling state up to a common ancestor component and pass down as props what you need.

Example:

```
const Header = ({ changeStyle }) => {
  return (
    <div class="container-fluid ">           
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col px-0">
          <div className="header d-flex justify-content-around">
            <Link to='/'>
              <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-lg img-btn"
                onClick={setBars}
              >
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} size="xl" />
              </button>
            </Link>
            <Link to='/video'>
              <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-lg img-btn"
                onClick={ChevronLeft}
              >
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBolt} size="xl" />
              </button>
            </Link>
            <Link to='/video'>
              <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-lg img-btn"
              >
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} size="xl" />
              </button>
            </Link>
            <Link to='/video'>
              <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-lg img-btn"
                onClick={changeStyle}
              >
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPowerOff} size="xl" />
              </button>
            </Link>   
          </div>
        </div>       
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
const App = () => {
  const [style, setStyle] = useState("profile-hidden");

  const changeStyle = () => {
    console.log("clicked");
    
    setStyle("profile-displayed");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={style}>
        <Header changeStyle={changeStyle} />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/video" element={<Video />} />
          <Route path="/" element={<Main />} />
          <Route path="/audio" element={<Audio />} />
          <Route path="/climate" element={<Climate />} />
          <Route path="/floorheat" element={<Floorheat />} />
          <Route path="/lights" element={<Lights />} />
          <Route path="/shades" element={<Shades />} />
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```